# Rails v6.0.0 push to Heroku fails - Rake & Bundler error msgs

Tags: rake, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

This is my first attempt to push a Rails v6.0.0 app to Heroku. The error msgs are:

```
Could not detect rake tasks
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_94b6a9e04d812c465a5480f59429532e/Gemfile.lock.
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
```

- I can run 'bundle exec rake -P', no problem.
- I have verified that bundler 2.0.1 is installed, no problem.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[A similar bugreport on the bundler repo](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6829#issuecomment-524490830) mentions that `bundler 2.0.1` conflicts with heroku. I've copied the following fix instructions from that comment:

- `gem install bundler -v 2.0.2`
- `bundle update --bundler`
- commit & push Gemfile.lock changes in your repo
- deploy with `git push heroku master`